# CKEditor editConfig not working in MVC view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I was trying to config CKEditor in in MVC view. It is working if change the configuration config.js file, but not in the view. I don't want change global level configuration change, just want change in view level.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        CKEDITOR.replaceAll('ckeditorText');

    });
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
        // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
        config.language = 'ru';
        // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    };
</script>
}
```

Comment: So your question is, is it possible to change CKEditor in the view level only and if so how?

Comment: yes. I want change CKEditor configuration view level.